# Alguém poderia me ajudar com esse código? o resultado está saindo incorreto

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){

  int salFixo = 0;

  int salFinal = 0;

  int vendas = 0;

  int comissao = 0;


  printf("Informe o salário fixo:\n");

  scanf("%d", &salFixo);

  printf("Informe o valor das vendas:\n");

  scanf("%d", &vendas);


  comissao = vendas * (4/100);

  salFinal = comissao + salFixo;

  printf("Seu salário final será de %d sendo %d de comissões.", salFinal, comissao);


}
```

As comissôes não estão sendo calculadas.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

O que ocorre é que está usando `int`, e `int` somente suporta números inteiros ("numeros sem virgula").

---

Então, se você faz: `(4/100)` isso é `0`. O que você espera é que isso seja `0.04`, mas como virgula não é suportado, isso é "arredondado para baixo".

---

Altere todos os `int` pra `double` ou `float` para que suporte casas decimas, ou faça um cast disso:

```
int main(){
    int salFixo = 0;
    printf("Informe o salário fixo:\n");
    scanf("%d", &salFixo);

    int vendas = 0;
    printf("Informe o valor das vendas:\n");
    scanf("%d", &vendas);


    float comissao = (float) vendas * (4.0F/100.0F);
    float salFinal = comissao + (float) salFixo;

    printf("Seu salário final será de %f sendo %f de comissões.", salFinal, comissao);
}
```

Note que, neste caso, usamos `float` e usamos `4.0F` e `100.0F` para indicar que isto é float. Usar o `(float) vendas` não é necessário, poderia usar somente `vendas`, o compilador faz a conversão (até onde eu sei). *Mas converter explicitamente deixa mais claro o nosso intuito.*

---

Se quiser pode passar tudo pra `float`/`double` e usar o `F`:

```
int main(){

    // Altera tudo pra float:
    float salFixo = 0;
    float salFinal = 0;
    float vendas = 0;
    float comissao = 0;


    printf("Informe o salário fixo:\n");

    scanf("%f", &salFixo);  // Altera para %f

    printf("Informe o valor das vendas:\n");

    scanf("%f", &vendas);   // Altera para %f


    comissao = vendas * (4.0F/100.0F); // Altere para 4.0F e 100.0F

    salFinal = comissao + salFixo;

    // Altere para %f
    printf("Seu salário final será de %f sendo %f de comissões.", salFinal, comissao);
}
```

---

Tanto `float` quanto `double` tem problemas de precisão, então se o valor estiver "errado", veja outras perguntas do SO que respondem isso.

Comment: muito obrigado pela explicação.

Answer (score -2):

```
    #include <stdio.h>

int main(){

  int salFixo = 0;

  int salFinal = 0;

  int vendas = 0;

  int comissao = 0;


  printf("Informe o salário fixo:\n");

  scanf("%d", &salFixo);

  printf("Informe o valor das vendas:\n");

  scanf("%d", &vendas);

comissao = (vendas/100*4);

  salFinal = comissao + salFixo;

  printf("Seu salário final será de %d sendo %d de comissões.", salFinal, comissao);


}
```

> Não sei exatamente onde estava o erro (não estudo C), mas mudei como a variavel de "comissao" estava sendo calculada e deu certo.

Comment: também ainda não sei onde esta o erro, mas mudar a forma que a variavel é calculada realmente ajudou. Obrigado